# Printing the current line in elixir source code

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, elixir

In elixir we have the Pseudo-variables `__MODULE__`, `__DIR__` et al. In erlang there is also the functionality to get the current line, using an erlang macro.

How do I get the current file line in elixir.

Something like

```
IO.puts __LINE__
```

Comment: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/debugging.html#dbg (added in Elixir 1.14) prints this info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all inside `__ENV__`:

```
IO.puts __ENV__.file
IO.puts __ENV__.line
```

Also see https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.Env.html

Comment: any reason why `__DIR__` gets special treatment and makes it to a special form

Comment: Maybe because it is used more often e. g. to find the path relative to the source file, maybe it's simply a legacy thing, I don't know.

Comment: so I have worked out how to redefine them myself so that is also no problem